# Error importing sql database #1050 - Table 'wp_calendar' already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I am trying to import a database to `phpmyadmin` and I am getting an error saying:

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_calendar` 
(
    `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `event_begin` date NOT NULL,
    `event_end` date NOT NULL,
    `event_title` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `event_desc` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `event_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_recur` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_repeats` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_author` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_category` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `event_link` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

MySQL said:

```
Documentation 1050 - Table 'wp_calendar' already exists
```

Any ideas how could I solve this?

Comment: Drop the table prior recreating or don't recreate it.

Comment: Which part of ***table ... already exists*** don't you understand? Seems pretty clear - you cannot create a table again, if it already exists. Either give it a different name, or **drop it** before running this script

Comment: sorry but I don't have any knowledge on php... I'm just trying to recover a backup from my wordpress website, and when I'm trying to upload the sql that I download from the backups, it comes with a message like this... How can I update the php and what and where exactly do I need to look for/change?

Comment: You could edit the query to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`wp_calendar\` ...`